# How to insert images into posts without using Add Media dialog

Tags: images, uploads

I want to simplify the process of inserting images when editing posts. In wordpress default, you have to click "Add Media" to show a popup dialog, upload images, choose from gallery.. it is too complicated.

My desired process is:

1. Click "Add Image" to show a dialog
2. Click "Choose File" and pick an image from your computer
3. Click "Upload" and wait for the file to be uploaded. Then image is
   inserted into post automatically

As an example, my desired process is just like the insert image button in the wordpress.stackoverflow.com rich text editor, you can click to see it (Sorry but I am not allowed to post images here)

I know stackoverflow upload images to a third party provider, but I want to use my own wordpress installation. 
Also, I don't care the Media management section (wp-admin/upload.php), I probably will remove it from admin panel.

My question is:

How can I implement a simplified upload images process in Wordpress? Any plugin available?

Comment: Are you using Wordpress 3.5? They've overhauled the whole image management process, and it's even easier to use than your described process. http://thenextweb.com/apps/2012/12/11/wordpress-3-5-brings-new-photo-flow-mobile-first-default-theme-and-retina-support/

Comment: Would this assume that the image being uploaded is properly proportioned?

Comment: According to me U need to make an post of that image automatically on upload?

Comment: I am using Wordpress 3.4, but i can upgrade to 3.5. I will see if the new process good.

Comment: kidakaka: I don't need crop or any other image manipulation.

Comment: vaibhav: I hope the image upload process as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress default media management system is pretty good and far better than what you want. However, you can use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to add image upload boxes in your post editor page.

Once the image is uploaded, you can display it in the editor using a shortcode `[acf field="{$field_name}"]`.

Check out [ACF Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) for all the details.

This plugin is very easy to use. However, your image may not be processed by WordPress and other image processing plugins that you may have or will have in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin .This will automatically make post on image upload

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/

And also the title of the image will be set from image files name. Which is too easy

Answer (score 0):

Completely without any "Add Media Dialog"? Upload images using FTP and insert the images into your post using the HTML view of the editor!

Now seriously: The "Add Media Dialog" in my opinion is just perfect for users who don't know how to upload images, crop them to a reasonable size and align them as preferred. I don't want to visit blog with 4000x3000 pixel images showing only at 10% of their original size, only because some other users don't need features like cropping.

I use the HTML view of the editor all the time and when I include images, I drag-drop them all together for upload and then themm all together, before writing the text around them. Or sometimes I just type the img tag directly into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired process is pretty much the same as what the native media features WordPress already includes for inserting media.

My desired process is:

```
Click "Add Image" to show a dialog

Click "Choose File" and pick an image from your computer

Click "Upload" and wait for the file to be uploaded. Then image is inserted into post automatically
```

However, you could create a custom field and meta box hooked into the position you want your image to display.

This would be more work than its worth because you'll need PHP code to hook the custom field to a function and then you'll need to code the meta box or use a plugin like ACF to create the add image box.

**You would only need to do this if you want images to display outside the content area covered by the wp editor.**

Another option is to [add PHP code to your functions file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127117/how-can-i-display-my-featured-image-correctly-inside-my-single-posts/127595#127595) which is hooked into the featured image so all you need to do is add a featured image which will display in the same position on all posts depending on the hook used in the code.